# Notice: array to string conversion in line

Tags: php

I have a problem getting to echo some data from my database: I have tried several things but it just won't work.

Here is my code:

```
$dbobject = new Company();
$where = "ID=1";
if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
    $dbobject->setPageno($_GET['pageno']);
}
$data = $dbobject->getData($where);
echo implode(' ',array_values($data));
```

I have tried the following also:

```
foreach ($data as $value){
    echo $value;
}
```

and

```
echo implode(" ",$data);
```

I know the data is there because I can get it with `print_r`.

Comment: What is the return type of the `getData` function? Are you sure it's an array of values? i.e. not multidimensional?

Comment: is $data really an array? don't dump with `print_r`, use `var_dump` instead - it prints out the type too (i think you get back false, or null)

Comment: NullPointer came up with the solution

Answer (score 1):

try

```
foreach ($data as $value){
echo implode(" ",$value);
}
```

Comment: That did it, thank you so much, I was about to go out of my mind, been looking at it for hours